# how to sort rows according to multiple dependencies

Tags: postgresql

The table has many columns, but for the problematic part let's assume only two, [ID] and [dependency].

[Dependency] means which [ID]s should be listed before this [ID].

Each row has its unique [ID] but it might have none, one or more dependencies in the [Dependency] column

| ID | Dependency |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 |
| 2 | null |
| 3 | 1,2 |
| 4 | 2 |
| 5 | 1,2,4 |

**Expected Result**

| ID | Dependency |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | null |
| 4 | 2 |
| 1 | 4 |
| 3 | 1,2 |
| 5 | 1,2,4 |

I have no prior experience in Postgres, I found this very useful:

```
SELECT aa.dep_id::integer FROM unnest(string_to_array(ss.dependency, ',')) aa(dep_id)
```

But still, I can't make it right.

EDIT: Added one row with 3 dependencies'

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/894c3/4

Comment: This probably requires a recursive query. `ORDER BY` does not do topological sorting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a recursive CTE:

```
WITH RECURSIVE o AS (
      SELECT ss.id, ss.dependency,
             1 AS level
      FROM ss
      WHERE dependency IS NULL
   UNION ALL
      SELECT ss.id, ss.dependency,
             o.level + 1
      FROM ss
         JOIN o
            ON o.id IN (SELECT x
                        FROM unnest(ss.dependency) AS x(x)
                       )
)
SELECT o.id, o.dependency
FROM o
GROUP BY o.id, o.dependency
ORDER BY max(o.level);
```

Comment: Hi, see the sqlFiddle link, this query is not working as expected.

Comment: sure, the result is in the wrong order. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/894c3/4

Comment: Each row should appear after all dependencies are listed. See expected results. First all rows with no dependencies, then rows that depend on IDs already listed, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

My working solution, I hope it can be improved

```
DO $do$
DECLARE v_RowCountInt  Int;
--copy all values to temp table
begin
--This is the origin table, all rows to sort
drop table if exists _tempAll;
create temp table _tempAll as select id, dependency from XXXXX;

-- create temp table for results
drop table if exists _tempSort;
create temp table _tempSort (
id integer
,dependency varchar
,pos serial primary key);

  -- move all IDs with no depencencies
WITH tmp AS (DELETE FROM _tempAll where dependency is null RETURNING id, dependency)
    INSERT INTO _tempSort ( id, dependency) 
    SELECT id, dependency FROM tmp;


GET DIAGNOSTICS v_RowCountInt = ROW_COUNT;

 while v_RowCountInt>0 loop

    -- move rows with all dependencies met     
 
    WITH tmp AS (DELETE FROM _tempAll a   
        where a.id in(SELECT  a.id FROM _tempSort s inner join _tempAll a on
                    s.id in (select split.dep_sid::integer  from unnest(string_to_array(a.dependency, ',')) split(dep_sid))
                    group by a.id, a.dependency
                    -- verify all dependencies are already sorted
                    having count(*)=(CHAR_LENGTH(a.dependency) - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(a.dependency, ',', ''))+1))
        RETURNING a.id, a.dependency)
        INSERT INTO _tempSort (id, dependency) 
        SELECT id, dependency FROM tmp;

    GET DIAGNOSTICS v_RowCountInt = ROW_COUNT;

end loop;

end;
$do$
```

Comment: This is working fine. Is it a way to transform the loop into recursive CTE?